# Pandas how to add the counters for matching rows between two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes, where I would like to add the another counter column for matching rows between these dataframes rows.

df1:

```
Id   val1  val2   val3
0     ab     ba     sx
1     bc     dc     xy
2.    ab     ba     ux
```

df2:

```
Id   val1  val2   val3
0     ab     ba      zx
1     bc     dc      vy
```

Expected result:
df3:

```
Id   val1  val2   val3  counter
0     ab     ba     sx       1
1     bc     dc     xy      1
2.    ab     ba     ux      2
```

I want here to match the `val1` and `val2` column and add the counter in *df3* for matched rows between these dataframes *df1* and *df2*.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverfwlow! Please, provide the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the matched rows via an inner merge, then use `groupby` + `cumcount` to add a counter:

```
res = df1.merge(df2.drop(['Id', 'val3'], 1), on=['val1', 'val2'], how='inner')\
         .sort_values('Id').reset_index(drop=True)

res['Counter'] = res.groupby(['val1', 'val2']).cumcount() + 1

print(res)

   Id val1 val2 val3  Counter
0   0   ab   ba   sx        1
1   1   bc   dc   xy        1
2   2   ab   ba   ux        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear what you want for output, but this might help you:

```
dfa = df1.groupby(['val1', 'val2'], as_index = false).size().rename(columns{0,'counter'}
```

Comment: Yes it helped and brings the idea to add the counters for matching rows between two dataframes.

Comment: Glad I can help. Do not forget to vote the answer if it helped you.